# UIToolbar and CGRectMake

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitoolbar, cgrectmake

I have 2 UIToolbar in one ViewControler.

I need to change their positin on rotating.

I add 2 outlets

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar2;
```

Connect them in IB
Now in viewcontroller.m i use this code

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        toolbar1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 44);
        toolbar2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 374, 1024, 44);
    }
    else
    {
        toolbar1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 44);
        toolbar2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 502, 768, 44);
    }
}
```

Promblem is - nothing changes!

How can i fix it?

P.S. With webviews it works

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` method called? If it is, are `toolbar1` and `toolbar2` non-nil?

Comment: what you mean by called? it works normally. 

they are not nil
add screenshot

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwGiJmMHSt-6ZDUxSi1mNXhHY1k/edit?usp=sharing - exaple of what i want to do, that doesnt works

Comment: I mean when you rotate your device, is the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` method executed? Use the debugger and put a breakpoint on the `if` statement. See if it is reached. If it is, verify at runtime that the two variables are not nil.

Comment: checked all, method works okay
variables are not nil

I put a link to zip file with example, that doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you Uncheck Autolayout in ViewController.xib, then this code always work.
Change height to see different and comment out all setting in other method.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    if  (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)){
        toolbar1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 20);
        toolbar2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 374, 1024, 20);
    } else {
        toolbar1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 44);
        toolbar2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 502, 768, 44);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw your code and I know what the problem is. You forgot to connect your elements in the Nib to the IBOutlets in your code.

[image]

After connecting the Outlets the example works. I tested it.

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: @nik1004 I'm afraid I don't know what you mean. I downloaded the example you shared and tried it and the toolbars didn't change their position. Then I noticed that neither toolbar1 nor toolbar2 were connected to the IBOutlets in code (see screenshot 2) so I went ahead, connected them and retried. After that the toolbars are changing their position. Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Yes, this works for example project, i have main one, where everything connected, doesnt work...

Comment: add screenshot of main project...

using the same code as in example